# Show a Tensor6 Cell Attribute in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I have some data in an HDF5 file, containing also stress and strain tensors for each cell type element. I created a XDMF file to describe the data, parts of it look like this:

```
 <Attribute Name="Displacement" AttributeType="Vector" Center="Node">
   <DataItem Dimensions="2673 3" Format="HDF" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" >
     cubetest2.h5:/Solution/Nodal displacements
   </DataItem>
 </Attribute>

 <Attribute Name="Force" AttributeType="Vector" Center="Node">
   <DataItem Dimensions="2673 3" Format="HDF" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" >
     cubetest2.h5:/Solution/Nodal forces
   </DataItem>
 </Attribute>

 <Attribute Name="eleStrain" AttributeType="Tensor6" Center="Cell">
   <DataItem Dimensions="2048 6" Format="HDF" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" >
       cubetest2.h5:/Solution/Element strain
   </DataItem>
 </Attribute>

 <Attribute Name="eleStress" AttributeType="Tensor6" Center="Cell">
   <DataItem Dimensions="2048 6" Format="HDF" NumberType="Float" Precision="8" >
       cubetest2.h5:/Solution/Element stress
   </DataItem>
 </Attribute>
```

while the vector values are just read fine, and I can create vector glyphs, the "Tensor Glyph" filter is always greyed out.
I suspect that ParaView creates a tensor with 9 components out of the six, but the [documentation for Tensor Glyph](https://www.paraview.org/ParaView/Doc/Nightly/www/py-doc/paraview.simple.TensorGlyph.html) states that it requires six values.

How is it possible to show the tensors, i.e. tell Paraview not to create a full symmetric tensor?

Comment: Wich version of ParaView are you using ?

Comment: @MathieuWestphal paraview version 5.4.1

Comment: How many components does your data arrays have ?

Comment: I have the six components of a symmetric tensor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tensor Glyph` Filter does not support Cell Data operation.

You should first convert your Dell Data to Point Data using `Cell Data To Point Data` Filter.